# how to suppress "PROGRESS REPORT" from Erlang interactive shell

Tags: erlang

I'm using Erlang/OTP 20 on macOS. Eshell prints multiple lines with heading "PROGRESS REPORT", I want it to not print that.

Inverse `grep`ing and similar work around are not desirable.

Here's a sample of statements getting printed:

> =PROGRESS REPORT==== 28-Aug-2017::22:39:40 ===
>             supervisor: {local,sasl_safe_sup}
>                started: [{pid,<0.59.0>},
>                          {id,alarm_handler},
>                          {mfargs,{alarm_handler,start_link,[]}},
>                          {restart_type,permanent},
>                          {shutdown,2000},
>                          {child_type,worker}]
>
> =PROGRESS REPORT==== 28-Aug-2017::22:39:40 ===
>             supervisor: {local,sasl_sup}
>                started: [{pid,<0.58.0>},
>                          {id,sasl_safe_sup},
>                          {mfargs,
>                              {supervisor,start_link,
>                                  [{local,sasl_safe_sup},sasl,safe]}},
>                          {restart_type,permanent},
>                          {shutdown,infinity},
>                          {child_type,supervisor}]
>
> =PROGRESS REPORT==== 28-Aug-2017::22:39:40 ===
>             supervisor: {local,sasl_sup}
>                started: [{pid,<0.60.0>},
>                          {id,release_handler},
>                          {mfargs,{release_handler,start_link,[]}},
>                          {restart_type,permanent},
>                          {shutdown,2000},
>                          {child_type,worker}]

Comment: To what end? Pls. elaborate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [the documentation for the `sasl` application](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sasl_app.html), you can suppress progress reports by setting the configuration parameter `errlog_type` to `error`.

You can specify it on the command line:

```
erl -sasl errlog_type error
```

Or, if you're using a `sys.config` file, add it there:

```
{sasl, [{errlog_type, error}]}
```

Setting it with `application:set_env` after the node has started won't work: it only takes effect if the value was set before the `sasl` application started.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the SASL app to start at all you can use a different [boot script](http://erlang.org/doc/system_principles/system_principles.html#boot-scripts):

`erl -boot start_clean`

This will disable SASL messages completely.